# Why is cardinality theorem not true by definition?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Theorem: Prove that for all natural numbers n and m, if $I_n \sim I_m$ then n = m.

It seems to me that this theorem is stating the following:
"If two sets have the same number of elements, then the number of elements each has are equal."

If that is a correct interpretation, how is the theorem not simply true by the definition of what it means to have the same number of elements? 
Additionally, why does the following proof fail to prove the theorem? Where does it assume something that I am now allowed to?

Proof:

Let m,n be arbitrary natural numbers, and assume $I_n \sim I_m$. By definition, |$I_m$| = m. Since $I_n \sim I_m$, it also follows by the definition of a finite set that |$I_m$| = n. Thus, n = m.

Comment: So what's the definition of $I_n$?

Comment: How do you know there's no bijection from a set of size $n$ to a set of size $m$? Your issue is that you assume that $|\cdot|$ gives a well-defined map; but if the theorem you stated is false, then it could be that a set have multiple sizes.

Comment: @Hayden these are finite sets, how could they have multiple sizes?

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity Well, they don't (hence the "Theorem"), but a priori you don't know it isn't possible unless you prove it.  In particular, you can't use it in a proof of said theorem.

Comment: @user160738 $I_n$ is the set of all positive integer values from 1 to n.

Comment: @Hayden Does the definition of a finite set not exclude the possibility that they have multiple sizes?

Comment: I suppose it might depend on your definition.  One definition is that a set is finite if there exists a well-ordering $\leq$ on it whose opposite order is also a well-ordering.  With that definition, the theorem appears non-trivial.  More than likely, your definition is close to something like "$A$ is finite if there exists $n$ and a bijection $f: A \to I_n$".  This doesn't say that $n$ is unique, however, and that's something you need to prove.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48407/discussion-between-ignorantcuriosity-and-hayden).